# DataLoader - pytorch inconsistency between cpu and mps - Apple Silicon

Tags: python, pytorch, mps, apple-m2

I got stuck on this inconsistency with DataLoader in Pytorch on Mac Apple Silicone.
If I use cpu `y` is interpreted correctly. However If I use mps it always returns vector with correct length, however only based on first element `y[0]`.

```py
import torch
from torch.utils.data import TensorDataset, random_split, DataLoader


device = torch.device("mps") 
X = torch.tensor([[[0.5,0.4], [0,0]],[[0.3,0.2], [0,0]],[[0.5,0.2], [0,0]],[[0.2,0.2], [0,0]]], dtype=torch.float32).to(device)
y = torch.tensor([1,0,0,0], dtype=torch.float32).to(device)

print(X.shape)
print(y.shape)
print(y)
dataset = TensorDataset(X, y)
train_size = int(0.5 * len(dataset))
test_size = len(dataset) - train_size
train_dataset, test_dataset = random_split(dataset, [train_size, test_size])
train_loader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=10, shuffle=True)

for i, (batch_data, batch_labels) in enumerate(train_loader):
    print(batch_data)
    print(batch_labels)
    break
```

for `batch_labels` on `mps` i always get tensor full of ones or zeroes based on first value in `y`

```
torch.Size([4, 2, 2])
torch.Size([4])
tensor([1., 0., 1., 0.], device='mps:0')
tensor([[[0.5000, 0.2000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000]],

        [[0.5000, 0.4000],
         [0.0000, 0.0000]]], device='mps:0')
tensor([1., 1.], device='mps:0')
```

Maybe it is related to [General MPS op coverage tracking issue #77764](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/77764)

Answer (score 1):

It is bug related to older versions of torch. 2.0.1 works just fine.
[Updated torch to 2.0.1](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/108045#issuecomment-1697241967)